# Difference between cold brew and iced coffee?

Tags: flavor, cold-brew, iced-coffee

What is the difference between cold brew and iced coffee?
Is cold brew better than iced coffee?

Answer (score 4):

Iced coffee is simply hot brewed coffee or espresso that has been poured over ice, and possibly mixed with contaminants like milk and sugar ;) 
Cold brew is coffee that has been brewed with cold water over a long period of time, usually 12-24 hours. The process eliminates a lot of the acidity in coffee, and produces a sweet, flavorful coffee when done properly. Some people like cold brew more than hot coffee, it's all just personal preference.